# Unable to bind Data Grid to my observable collection of class object

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I am writing a GUI where I have multiple tabs. each tab has a header and content. Tab is bonded to observable collections of object Item. The content of the tab is a DataGrid which i want to bind to another object LogGUIData (which is a class member variable of Item). Data is populated by socket read. I tired to find lot of answers but couldn't find any. I know I am missing somewhere something as I am new to C# and WPF programming. My code is below. Thanks in advance

```
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DataGrid Name="dgLogdata"  Margin="10" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ItemsSource="{Binding LogDataOC, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" >                              
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header" Binding="{Binding strHeaderData}" FontFamily="Arial" />
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

c# code

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {

            public string Header { get; set; }

            public static int _count = -1;
            public int Count
            {
                get { return _count; }
                set { _count = value; }
            }


            public Item()
            {
                LogDataOC = new ObservableCollection<GUILogData>();
                _count++;//increase the count of tab. This will represent the index of the tab
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                var handler = PropertyChanged;
                handler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

            private ObservableCollection<GUILogData> _logDataOC { get; set; }

            public ObservableCollection<GUILogData> LogDataOC
            {
                get { return _logDataOC; }
                set
                {
                    _logDataOC = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("LogDataOC");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is your problem and why you set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` and do not create columns manually.

Comment: i was unable to bind the LogGUIData to the grid column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was binding to the private member instead of the property. 
Modified Xaml code :

```
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DataGrid Name="dgLogdata"  Margin="10" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ItemsSource="{Binding LogDataOC, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" >                              
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    *<DataGridTextColumn Header="Header" Binding="{Binding HeaderData}" FontFamily="Arial" />*                                  
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```